# Eclipse CDT extend to build an additional language

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to extend the CDT language plugin for gnu c, to create some kind of new language based on this.

The new language should have a different visual appearence in editor. I would like to color a method body in gray if there is a special pre-processor directive in front of (like an annotation).

Does anybody know where to extend the GCC language for a modification like this?

---

---

EDIT1:

As example I want that the colour of the method body of **specialFunction** to be gray, as a reason of an example annotation ->  **#annotation**

```
#annotation
int specialFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

---

---

EDIT2:

What i have tried so far is to build a "extended language". The plan was to highlight a preprocessor position and also save the position so that the method below would be colored. I managed to get the preprocessor keyword colored but not how to work on method bodies color.

```
public class OwnKeyWords extends GCCLanguage implements ICLanguageKeywords

@Override
public String[] getPreprocessorKeywords() {
    //System.out.println("Called keywords" + timesPre++);
    return new String[]{
            "hide",
            "show"
    };
}
```

Example to be colored:

```
#hide
int specialFunction(){
    return 1;
}
```

In the example above "hide" would be highlighted.

---

---

EDIT3:

I tried to implement ISemanticHighlighter and tried a few ways to highlight my code:

```
CVariable
CFunction
ObjectStyleMacro
...
```

But non of them where suitable to highlight a method body with a preprocessor directive or anything else on top.

Also the note in ISemanticHighlighter:

```
 * NOTE: Implementors are not allowed to keep a reference on the token or on any object retrieved from the
 * token.
```

Is not what I want to achieve, because I would like to keep reference to the highlighted object for later operations.

Maybe the org.eclipse.cdt.ui.text.folding.DefaultCFoldingStructureProvider would be an option too, there I couldn't colour the instrumentation, I could instead hide it.

Comment: This is a very broad question as currently asked, so I can't provide a full answer. Have a look though at http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_cdt_core_language.html?cp=14_1_1_7 and how that extension point is used in CDT itself to define the GCC language variant or one of the other similar languages like Qt.

Comment: @JonahGraham specified the question further

Comment: "Is not what I want to achieve, because I would like to keep reference to the highlighted object for later operations." -- that does not sound right in any respects, you are generally in all APIs in CDT not allowed to keep references to AST nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not sound like a new language so much as semantic highlighting.

CDT has a great extension point called `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.semanticHighlighting` that allows you to define custom semantic highlighting rules.

Here is an example of the plugin.xml entry:

```
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.cdt.ui.semanticHighlighting">
      <semanticHighlighting
            class="com.example.SemanticHighlighter"
            defaultBold="true"
            defaultEnabled="true"
            defaultTextColor="35,0,35"
            displayName="Example Semantic Highlighter"
            id="com.example.SemanticHighlighter"
            preferenceKey="com.example.SemanticHighlighter.pref"
            priority="5">
      </semanticHighlighting>
   </extension>
```

Then in your `com.example.SemanticHighlighter` you implement the `org.eclipse.cdt.ui.text.ISemanticHighlighter` interface. There is only one method, `consumes` that takes a `ISemanticToken`. Analyse the token to see if it is relevant to your highlighter and return true to have it highlighted.

Here is a trivial implementation of the method:

```java
@Override
public boolean consumes(ISemanticToken token) {
    IBinding binding = token.getBinding();
    if (binding instanceof IFunction) {
        IASTNode node = token.getNode();
        if (binding != null && node instanceof IASTName && ((IASTName) node).isReference()) {
            String n = binding.getName();
            if ("MySpecialFunction".equals(n)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Once implemented, users can modify the colour and applicability via the preference page `C/C++` - `Editor` - `Syntax Coloring`:

[image: highlighting preference page]

Comment: Should your example highlight a method body called from a method MySpecialFunction? I am not able to get it running. Edited my question further.

Comment: What have you managed to get running, not running. the example should highlight a call to a function called MySpecialFunction because I am examining the node to see if it is a reference to such a function. Obviously your case will be different. Please post what you have actually tried and I (and others hopefully) will be able to help.

Comment: I didn't knew that a call would be highlighted, thought the method body would be. Edited my post again. Managed to get your example running.

Comment: Glad you got the example running. Unfortunately your updated post only further explains your problem, but does not show what further things you have tried, e.g. have you put a bp inside consumes() to observe what things CDT allows you to (trivially) do semantic highlighting on?

Comment: I had a closer look, and I don't think that this (trivial) way will be my way, as you can see in my thoughts in edit3. But maybe I am wrong and the method body highlight is just one move away?

Comment: Oh well, hopefully exploring how semantic highlighting is implemented will be sufficient for you to figure out how to implement your case. extending GCCLanguage to do the parsing, plus other aspects of CDT to do the highlighting will probably be necessary. Unfortunately that is getting beyond the scope of what I am able to answer for free on a stack overflow question (be in touch with my privately, via my profile if you are interested).

Comment: In addition, have a look at SemanticHighlightingReconciler, that is the class that eventually calls your ISemanticHighlighter, but it may be that writing your own reconciler with its own ASTVisitor is what is needed here.

Comment: I have one last question: Would it be easier to fold a code snippet or to colour it? Do you maybe know an example where ICFoldingStructureProvider where used to collapse some specified part?

Comment: My guess is folding as there are extension points to add your own folding provider, but really not sure on that.

Comment: Didn't found a example on how to extend that. "Simpliest" example had over 2000 lines :-/

Comment: Sorry can't help more on that, I'll be on the lookout for any new questions on SO if you have some new specific problems as you try and resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `ISemanticHighlighter` to do the kind of highlighting you want.

For your example of coloring the body of a function with a particular annotation, it could work like this:

```
class MyHighlighter implements ISemanticHighlighter {
    @Override
    public boolean consumes(ISemanticToken token) {
        IASTNode node = token.getNode();

        // Walk up the AST to determine if 'node' is inside a function body.
        // If it's not, return false.

        // Navigate the AST some more to examine what comes before the
        // function's declaration. If it's the annotation in question,
        // return true. Otherwise, return false.
    }
}
```

I left out the details of how to navigate the AST, but CDT has a pretty rich AST API so it's definitely doable. Feel free to ask specific questions if you have them.